# the Accessing commented HTML Lines with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to webscrape stats from this specific webpage: https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/louisville/2016/gamelog/

However, the table for the 'Defensive Game Log' appears to be commented out when I look at the HTML source (starts with <...!-- and ends with -->)

Because of this, when attempting to use BeautifulSoup4 the following code only grabs the offensive data that is not commented out while the defensive data is commented out.

```
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

accessurl = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/oklahoma-state/2016/gamelog/'
req = Request(accessurl)
link = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(link.read(), "lxml")


tables = soup.find_all(['th', 'tr'])
my_table = tables[0]
rows = my_table.findChildren(['tr'])
for row in rows:
    cells = row.findChildren('td')
    for cell in cells:
        value = cell.string
        print(value)
```

I am curious if there are any solutions to be able to add all of the defensive values into a list the same way the offensive data is stored be it inside or outside of BeautifulSoup4. Thanks!

Note that I added onto solution given below derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table):

```
data = []

table = defensive_log
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values
```

Comment: What do you mean by "commented out"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Comment` object will give you what you want:

```
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

accessurl = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/oklahoma-state/2016/gamelog/'
req = Request(accessurl)
link = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(link, "lxml")

comments=soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))
for comment in comments:
    comment=BeautifulSoup(str(comment), 'lxml')
    defensive_log = comment.find('table') #search as ordinary tag
    if defensive_log:
        break
```

Comment: @Storm, any feedback? did my solution help?

Comment: Sorry for the long time required to get back to you--I've been moving and finally back on the project. I am running through it now to attempt to incorporate it.

Comment: I added the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table). It allowed me to put this into a table.  I am putting the final code string in the question above.

Comment: Sorry i don't completely understand you. So you mean that you've made a workaround but now trying to achieve the goal my way?