# BeautifulSoup findAll variable type issue

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some information from some HTML using python's BeautifulSoup.

Sudsection of the HTML:

```
<div class="ui-grid-canvas">
                            <!-- -->
                            <div class="ui-grid-row" ng-class="{'ui-grid-tree-header-row': row.treeLevel &gt; -1, 'ui-grid-row-dirty': row.isDirty, 'ui-grid-row-saving': row.isSaving, 'ui-grid-row-error': row.isError,'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}" ng-repeat="(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index" ng-style="Viewport.rowStyle(rowRenderIndex)">
                                <div role="row" row-render-index="rowRenderIndex" ui-grid-row="row">
                                    <div role="row">
                                        <!-- -->
                                        <div class="ui-grid-cell ui-grid-coluiGrid-0005" ng-class="{sorted: col.name==$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.datatableImpl.sortedColumn}" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" role="gridcell" tabindex="0" ui-grid-cell="">
                                            <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-bind-html="row.entity[col.field].content" title="Alnwick-Haldimand">Alnwick-Haldimand</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- -->
                                        <div class="ui-grid-cell ui-grid-coluiGrid-0006" ng-class="{sorted: col.name==$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.datatableImpl.sortedColumn}" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" role="gridcell" tabindex="0" ui-grid-cell="">
                                            <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-bind-html="row.entity[col.field].content" title="Alderville Community Centre">Alderville Community Centre</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- -->
                                        <div class="ui-grid-cell ui-grid-coluiGrid-0007" ng-class="{sorted: col.name==$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.datatableImpl.sortedColumn}" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" role="gridcell" tabindex="0" ui-grid-cell="">
                                            <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-bind-html="row.entity[col.field].content" title="Under construction">Under construction</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- -->
                                        <div class="ui-grid-cell ui-grid-coluiGrid-0008" ng-class="{sorted: col.name==$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.datatableImpl.sortedColumn}" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" role="gridcell" tabindex="0" ui-grid-cell="">
                                            <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-bind-html="row.entity[col.field].content" title="March 2018">March 2018</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- -->
                                <!-- -->
                            </div>
```

I'm encountering a strange error. The following is a block of code for which the problem is occuring:

```
 table = page_soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class" : "ui-grid-canvas"})
 print(type(table[0]))

 rows = table[0].findAll('div',attrs={"class": "ui-grid-row"})
 print(type(rows[0]))

 cell = rows[0].findALL('div')
 print(type(cells))
```

These lines return the following:

```
 <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
 <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

 <ipython-input-56-13fce9e4b865> in <module>()
       5 print(type(rows[0]))  
       6 
 ----> 7 cell = rows[0].findALL('div')
       8 print(type(cells))

 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Why is this returning a type error when the check on the variable type directly above indicates that it is a bs4.element.Tag which worked in the case of the table variable?

Using Ubuntu, Python 3.6 and BS4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because from the 2nd line you have *comments* (with these lines: `<!-- -->`), not ordinary markup elements. They're normally not caught by `BeautifulSoup` methods. And that's why your `rows` element is empty.

What you need to access comments is to use `Comment` object from `bs4`.
I've answered a similar question here:
[Accessing commented HTML Lines with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123495/accessing-commented-html-lines-with-beautifulsoup/45126730#45126730)