# How To Import Web Table Content Into Excel And Then Send It Through Email In Python

Tags: python-2.7, web, excel-2007

Although I tried to get this coding done using pandas, xlrd etc libraries, but not able to get success till now. 
Problem Statement:
So I have a website that is having two tables and I need to import both the tables into Excel and then filter it on date column and send the output on an email address.

Can someone help on this...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are a new contributor. Welcome, with this in mind I'll try to leave some nice resources that will give you a more holistic idea of solving the problem at hand.

For scraping the tables:
BeautifulSoup has already completed templates out there for parsing through tables. This is touched on in another question ([python BeautifulSoup parsing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table))

For manipulating excel data:
Openpyxl is a library that I have a small amount of experience with. It has at least limited functionality in manipulating excel spreadsheets. Here is a good resource for learning this (https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/)

For sending the files in an email:
Python has a library for Simple Mail Transfer Protocol, what email often uses. The smtp and email modules make this possible, although I haven't done it personally. 
(https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.html#module-email)
(https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/smtplib.html#module-smtplib)

Best of luck!

Comment: I tried to read table content but got below error :

import pandas as pd
con = pd.read_html("https://confluence.hk.hsbc/display/cvit/Release+Calendar")
con.to_csv(r"C:\Users\44101400\Release Comm Project\mydata.csv", index=False)

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-1bcb116dc3d4> in <module>()
----> 1 con.to_csv(r"C:\Users\44101400\Release Comm Project\mydata.csv", index=False)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'