# Scrape <tr> tag if <td> tag has attribute

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape data from a table, taking whole row `<tr>` if there is a `<td BGCOLOR="#D42A2A">` in the row

The html looks like this (there are more than 2 rows):

```
<tr bgcolor="#f4f4f4">
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;ITEM_1&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:46&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Connected&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:00&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP" bgcolor="#55aa2a">&nbsp;--:--:--&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;01:25:00 &nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp; 22:00:00&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;ITEM_2&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:46&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Connected&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;191&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:01&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP" bgcolor="#55aa2a">&nbsp;--:--:--&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;01:25:00 &nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp; 22:00:00&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;ITEM_3&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:59:02&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Connected&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;36&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;36&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:01&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP" bgcolor="#d42a2a">&nbsp;--:--:--&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;03:10:00 &nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp; 22:00:00&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table) but the answer here gives all rows in a table instead of rows that contain the necessary attribute

So my code so far looks like:

```
data = []

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
```

then I scrape the site again to find the bgcolor attribute, add it to list, append list to frame and drop any row that doesn't have the correct bgcolor.

This is all quite inefficient

How can I scrape the html to take rows from the table only if bgcolor exists in td.attrs of the row

EDIT: Once the solutions below are applied to the entire html, the script returns empty lists (and that is my fault for not including more html). This html below is more complete version where more tags are included.

```
<html><head><title></title><style type="text/css">
BODY {
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
background-color: #FFFFFF
;}TABLE {
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;}
DIV.boldText {
font-size: 11px;font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="10">
</head><body>
<form name="DataViewChooser">
<hr width="95%" align="CENTER" color="#55aa2a">
<table width="95%" align="CENTER">
<tbody><tr><td width="40" height="65" title="(c) ITEMS"><img 
src="/icons/geneos_logo.png"></td>
<td width="25" align="LEFT">
<img title="Refresh" style="cursor: hand;" onclick="reloadPage()" 
src="/icons/refresh.png"></td>
<td width="25" title="Show Fail and Warning Only" align="LEFT"><img 
style="cursor: hand;" onclick="userContractView()" src="/icons/minimise.png"></td>
<td width="25" align="LEFT"><img title="Home" style="cursor: hand;" onclick="goHome()" src="/icons/up.png"></td>
<td align="RIGHT" nowrap="NOWRAP"><img src="/icons/hostgreen.gif">
<div class="boldText">&nbsp;DASHBOARD-CV_AMER_Dashboard</div>&nbsp; [GROUP]
</td>
</tr></tbody></table><hr width="95%" align="CENTER" color="#55aa2a"></form>
<br><table width="95%" align="CENTER"><tbody><tr><td><table>
<tbody><tr><th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;AMER&nbsp; 
</th>
<td nowrap="NOWRAP" bgcolor="#55aa2a">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
</tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
<br><table width="99%" align="CENTER">
<tbody><tr bgcolor="#c0c0c0">
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;RowName&nbsp;</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Gateway_updatetime&nbsp; 
</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Gateway_state&nbsp;</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;OrdersCleared&nbsp;</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Ticketsread&nbsp;</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;OrdersNotCleared&nbsp; 
</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;TicketsNotCleared&nbsp; 
</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;LastReadingtime&nbsp; 
</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;LastClearingtime&nbsp; 
</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;ClearingInProgress&nbsp; 
</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;YestVolumes&nbsp;</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Starttime&nbsp;</th>
<th height="20" align="LEFT" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Stoptime&nbsp;</th>
</tr><tr bgcolor="#f4f4f4">
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;ITEM_4&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:46&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Connected&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:00&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP" bgcolor="#d42a2a">&nbsp;--:--:--&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;01:25:00 &nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp; 22:00:00&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;ITEM_5&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:46&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Connected&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;191&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:01&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP" bgcolor="#55aa2a">&nbsp;--:--:--&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;01:25:00 &nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp; 22:00:00&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table><script language="JavaScript" src="/cookie.js"></script>
</body></html>'''
```

It is also worth noting that I am using urllib.request to open the url then parsing with BS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a [*searching function*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) where you can check the name of the tag to be `tr` as well as check that the row contains a `td` element with `bgcolor="#D42A2A"`:

```
def rows_with_desired_bgcolor(elm):
    return elm.name == 'tr' and elm.find('td', bgcolor="#D42A2A")

table_body.find_all(rows_with_desired_bgcolor)
```

You could, of course, do the same check in a list comprehension directly:

```
[tr for tr in table_body('tr') if tr.find('td', bgcolor="#D42A2A")]
```

where `table_body('tr')` is a shortcut to `table_body.find_all('tr')`.

Comment: I like your list comprehension, but it produces an empty list

Comment: @swagless_monk ok, have you tried lower-casing the `bgcolor` value?

Comment: Possible to get text only? I use `tr.text`, but need something like `tr.strip`

Comment: @swagless_monk you could do `.get_text(strip=True)` I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(content, 'html.parser')
results = [i for i in d.find_all('tr') if any(c.attrs.get('bgcolor') == "#d42a2a" for c in i.find_all('td'))]
```

Output:

```
[<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> ITEM_3 </td>
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> 07:59:02 </td>
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> Connected </td>
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> 0 </td>
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> 36 </td>
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> 0 </td>
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> 36 </td>
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> 07:58:01 </td>
  <td bgcolor="#d42a2a" height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> --:--:-- </td>
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> 0 </td>
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> 0 </td>
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP"> 03:10:00  </td>
  <td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">  22:00:00 </td>
 </tr>]
```

Comment: You could avoid using `find_all()` + `any()` as you could just do the `.find()` operation directly.

Comment: This worked perfect! I select other as answer bc it is one liner.

Comment: @swagless_monk Glad to help! This is a one liner too, thought. `table_body` in alecxe's answer is a `BeautifulSoup` object such as `soup(content, 'html.parser')` that has to be initialized on a different line. If you do want a single line solution, then replace `d` with `soup(content, 'html.parser')` in the comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

find all `td` contains `bgcolor="#d42a2a"` then select the `.parent`

```
cells = table_body.find_all('td', bgcolor="#d42a2a")
for cell in cells:
    print(cell.parent) 
    # <tr>...<td bgcolor="#d42a2a">...</tr>
```

Comment: Did you test and thats the result you got?

Comment: Im certain it is not your code, but my env. Let me edit some more

Comment: This worked great, thanks! I selected @alecxe as answer bc its one liner