# lxml returned me a list but it's empty

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml, xml.etree

I was trying to make a list of all the top 1000 instagramer's acount from this website:'https://hypeauditor.com/top-instagram/'.
The list that returns from lxml is empty for both lxml.html and lxml.etree.

I tried to delete tbody, delete text(), and upper xpath, but it all failed.
what worth noticing is that, with upper xpath, it did return me something, but it is all but /n.

I first tried lxml.etree

```
market_url='https://hypeauditor.com/top-instagram/'
r_market=requests.get(market_url)
s_market=etree.HTML(r_market)`
file_market=s_market.xpath('//*[@id="bloggers-top-table"]/tr[1]/td[3]/a/text()')
```

then I also tried lxml.html.

```
tree=html.fromstring(r_market.content)
result=tree.xpath('//*[@id="bloggers-top-table"]/tr/td/h4/text()')
```

furthermore, I tried this xpath:

```
s_market.xpath('//*[@id="bloggers-top-table"]/tbody/text()')
```

It did not give me any error. But after all the attempts, it still gives me wether empty list or a list full of n/.

I am not really experienced in web scraping so it is possible that I have just made a stupid error somewhere, but since without the data I can not start my machine learning model, I am really struggling, pls help.

Comment: were you after the entire table or just certain column(s)?

Comment: I am only after the column for the instagramer's account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will definitely want to get acquainted with the package [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) which allows you navigate a web page's content in python.

**Using BeautifulSoup:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://hypeauditor.com/top-instagram/'
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

top_bloggers = soup.find('table', id="bloggers-top-table")
table_body = top_bloggers.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

# For all data:
# Will retrieve a list of lists, good for inputting to pandas

data=[]

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values


# For just handles:
# Will retrieve a list of handles, only

handles=[]

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    values = cols[3].text.strip().split('\n')
    handles.append(values[-1])
```

> *The for loop I use for rows is sourced from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23377804)*

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and passionate answer, my question is solved. I will look into Beautiful Soup for sure.

Comment: Just one more question, hope this is not too much to ask. How do I scrap all pages of the table instead of the first one?

Comment: Are you asking about additional tables on this specific web page? Or additional web pages?

Comment: like, getting tables on  'https://hypeauditor.com/top-instagram/p=2' and all the way to 20.

Comment: You can build a for loop or while loop to cycle through each of the id's in the url. For example: `urls = ['https://hypeauditor.com/top-instagram/p2=p{i}') for i in range(1,100)]`

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do this would be to use `pandas`. It can read simple HTML Tables like this no problem. Try the following code to **scrape** the whole table.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://hypeauditor.com/top-instagram/')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more lightweight way of getting just that column using nth-of-type. You should find this faster.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://hypeauditor.com/top-instagram/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
accounts = [item.text.strip().split('\n') for item in soup.select('#bloggers-top-table td:nth-of-type(4)')][1:]
print(accounts)
```