# Create a Dataframe from HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to read a table from a web-page. Generally, my company has strict authentication policies restricting us in the way we can scrape the data.
But the following code is how I am trying to use to do the same

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth, OPTIONAL
import os
import lxml.html as LH
import requests
import pandas as pd

cert = r"C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\cacert.pem"
os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = cert
kerberos = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL)
session = requests.Session()

link = 'weblink'
data=session.get(link,auth=kerberos,verify=False).content.decode("latin-1")
```

And that leaves me with the entire HTML of the webpage in "data".
How do I convert this into a dataframe?

Note : I couldn't provide the weblink due to privacy concerns.. I was just wondering if there was a general way which I can use to tackle this situation.

Comment: How could we help without knowing anything about the data?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a procedure to convert the HTML into a dataframe.
That's what the question is about

Comment: [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) if there are tables, they can be read directly into pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table), using [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

From there, you'll have to create the data frame itself, but you will have passed the '*procedure to convert the HTML into*' a data structure step.  (that is, read the HTML table into a list or dictionary, and then transform it into a dataframe)

## Edit 1

Actually, you can use Pandas' [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html).  You might need Beautifulsoup still to get exactly what you want, but depending on how the source HTML looks like, it might be enough alone.