# Python is giving me both columns of a table I a scraping, but I only want it to give me one of the columns

Tags: python, web-scraping, multiple-columns, web-inspector

I am using Python to scrape the names of the Alaska Supreme Court justices from Ballotpedia (https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court). My current code is giving me both the names of the justices as well as the names of the persons in the "Appointed by" column. Here is my current code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court']

temp_dict = {}

for page in list:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in soup.select("table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter a")]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dict, 
orient='index').transpose()
df.to_csv('18-TEST.csv')
```

I've been trying to work with this line:

```
temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in soup.select("table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter a")]
```

I'm a little inexperienced using the inspect function on webpages, so I may be trying the wrong thing when I try to put "tr" or "td" (which I am finding under "tbody") after "tablesorter". I'm a bit lost at this point and am having trouble finding resources on this. Would you be able to help me to get python to give me the judge column but not the appointed by column? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to share another approach to get you table in desired format :

```
import pandas as pd
# extracting table and making it dataframe
frame = pd.read_html('https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court',attrs={"class":"wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"})[0]

# drop unwanted columns
frame.drop("Appointed By", axis=1, inplace=True)

# save dataframe as csv
frame.to_csv("desired/path/output.csv", index=False)
```

Printing **frame** would give output as :
|Judge|
|-----|
|   Daniel Winfree|
|   Joel Harold Bolger|
|   Peter Jon Maassen|
|   Susan Carney|
|   Dario Borghesan|

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to transition what you gave me to a list now, but am having trouble when the csv is only showing the judges from the last element of the list. Here is what I am using:

import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Ohio_Supreme_Court', 

for page in list:
    frame = pd.read_html(page,attrs={"class":"wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"})[0]

    frame.drop("Appointed By", axis=1, inplace=True)

frame.to_csv("18-TEST.csv", index=False)

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

There are different options to get the result.

### Option#1

Slice the list and pick every second element:

```
soup.select("table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter a")][0::2]
```

**Example:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

lst = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court']

temp_dict = {}

for page in lst:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in soup.select("table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter a")][0::2]

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dict, orient='index').transpose().to_csv('18-TEST.csv', index=False)
```

### Option#2

Make your selection more specific and select only the first `td` in a `tr`:

```
soup.select("table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter  tr > td:nth-of-type(1)")]
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court']

temp_dict = {}

for page in list:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in soup.select("table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter  tr > td:nth-of-type(1)")]

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dict, orient='index').transpose().to_csv('18-TEST.csv', index=False)
```

### Option#3

Use `pandas` functionality `read_html()`

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court')[2]
df.Judge.to_csv('18-TEST.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please note that this is code cannibalised from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table).

Now, if you don't know how many rows or columns you have, this gives you a dataframe with all the columns, corresponding to the table on the webpage. Feel free to drop one of the columns if you don't need it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# I'll do it for the one page example
page = 'https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court'

temp_dict = {}
r = requests.get(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

# this finds the first table with the class specified
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'})
# get all rows of the above table
rows = table.find_all('tr') 
data = []
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
# turn it into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```