# How to store info from a variable sized HTML table as Python variables

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have this 2 by 2 HTML table (header + 1 row at first).

```
<table id="table">
<thead><tr><th> 1 </th><th> 2 </th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td> body1 </th><td> body2 </th></td></tbody>
</table>
```

I added JavaScript functions to buttons on the page that will add and delete rows if the user chooses to.
My question is: how can I store the information on this variable-size table into Python variables. I am trying to scrape/parse it, but I haven't been able to collect the information in order to store it.
I've tried 2 different approaches:

```
url = "http://myprojecturl.com" # assume this is correct
page = urlopen(url)
html_bytes = page.read()
html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
table = html.find("table") 
print(table)
```

returns -1

```
html_file = open("http://myprojecturl.com")
html_content = html_file.read()
parsed_html = etree.HTML(html_content)
print(html_content)
html_tables = parsed_html.findall("table/tbody") # i've tried adding "<>" to this parameter and using other tags
```

returns an empty list

I have reason to believe the path is correct, and maybe the types being returned are different than what I print.
Any suggestions on a correction or different approach are much appreciated.

Comment: You could use `BeautifulSoup` https://stackoverflow.com/a/23377804/7942856

Comment: why are you trying to do this anyway? why not send the data to your python side via ajax in button event handler ?

Comment: @aSaffaryThis is for the final project of a course I'm taking. I'm not familiar with JavaScript and I am somewhat new to coding. Thanks for the suggestion, it looks like this will be the ideal