# How can I extract data from a web page and turn it into proper Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, here is an address: https://pesdb.net/pes2021/?id=44379
There seems to be no api call (I am pretty new to this but I checked XHR in network monitor and there are no relevant json calls).

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code and ask specific question about a problem you are stuck with. Also what is expected output?

Comment: I assume he wants to know about web scraping, but doesn't know what it is, or where to start.

Comment: @nihilok Right. My first goal is to just scrape the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61448317/14266189) of how to parse an html table, with just the Pandas/requests library.

According to [the latest docs](https://pythonbasics.org/pandas-web-scraping/), you can skip the requests call in that answer, but you will need to install dependencies:

`pip install lxml html5lib beautifulsoup4`

then you can do something like this:

```py
df_list = pd.read_html('https://pesdb.net/pes2021/?id=44379')    # this parses all the tables in webpages to a list
df = df_list[0]                   # the first table on the page
print(df)                         # this is your dataframe!
```

Generally, Beautiful Soup 4 is the most popular Python library for webscraping.

You can read some [examples here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quick-start)

Alternatively you could perform a GET request to the site and manually parse the response. (Most difficult / pointless)