# extract word from after scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web, url, beautifulsoup

I had gathered some infos using BeautifulSoup4 in the webpage: https://www.peakbagger.com/list.aspx?lid=5651

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.peakbagger.com/list.aspx?lid=5651'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

row = soup.find('tr') 
row

rows = soup.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:          
    print(row.get_text())
```

I would want to print the word so that each can be shown in each different sections, e.g.

before:

1.Fuji-sanKanto3776Yamanashi-ken/Shizuoka-kenHonshu3776318

2.Kita-dakeChubu3192Yamanashi-kenHonshu223731

after:

(a= )

Fuji-san

Kita-dake

...

(b=)

Kanto

Chubu

...

(c=)

3776

3192

...

for every of the lines starting from 1. to 100.

Shall I use a for loop or split to break each word?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe this is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table

Comment: Hi, I had tried but I think it gave me an error of 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}
r = requests.get("https://www.peakbagger.com/list.aspx?lid=5651")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", class_="gray")
header = [th.get_text(strip=True) for th in table.tr.select("th")][1:]
header.insert(0, 'S.No')

all_data = []
for row in table.select("tr:has(td)"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td")]
    all_data.append(tds)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=header)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

output:

```
 S.No         Peak        Section  ... Range (Level 3) Prom-M Ascents
0     1.     Fuji-san          Kanto  ...          Honshu   3776     318
1     2.    Kita-dake          Chubu  ...          Honshu   2237      31
2     3.  Hotaka-dake          Chubu  ...          Honshu   2305      23
3     4.    Aino-dake          Chubu  ...          Honshu    299      17
4     5.  Yariga-take          Chubu  ...          Honshu    432      29
..   ...          ...            ...  ...             ...    ...     ...
95   96.  Meakan-dake       Hokkaido  ...        Hokkaido   1147       7
96   97.    Amagi-san          Chubu  ...          Honshu   1004      14
97   98.   Ibuki-yama  Western Japan  ...          Honshu    657       8
98   99.  Kaimon-dake  Western Japan  ...          Kyushu    867       9
99  100.  Tsukuba-san          Kanto  ...          Honshu    797      20
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. What if I only need the first 4 columns?

Comment: I modify the code for 4 column

Comment: Maybe, shall I rephrase ? I hope to get only the no., peak, section and elev columns. Is there a way I can delete the rest?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: Just another question, how do I get the latitude and longitude for each of the links?

Comment: you need to chek `href` tag which I helpful to get latitude and longitude

Comment: I think your problem is solve  now