# how to pick specific table rows by comparing its inner table cells with given criteria?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, traversal

** I want to grab all the united states proxies from the site https://sslproxies.org/
I have grabbed all rows but unable to pick only those proxy records which have united states country
then I want to grab individual USA proxy with respective port and save them **

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# loading web page
r = requests.get("https://sslproxies.org/")
# convert to a beautiful-soup object
webpage = bs(r.content, "html.parser")
rows = iter(webpage.find('table').find_all('tr'))
for row in rows:
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        print(cell)
    print() ```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to directly use `pandas` to read and extract the table, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table).

Otherwise, you can check if any cell in a row contains "United States" and then print data from the first two columns for this row:

```py
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    if "United States" in cols:
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
```

Complete code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

# loading web page
r = requests.get("https://sslproxies.org/")
# convert to a beautiful-soup object
webpage = bs(r.content, "html.parser")

data = list()

rows = iter(webpage.find('table').find_all('tr'))
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    if "United States" in cols:
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

print(data)
```

The object `data` will contain all the information you need:

```
                 IP  Port Code        Country    Anonymity Google Https         Last Checked
0       168.8.172.2    80   US  United States  elite proxy     no   yes          17 secs ago
1     20.47.108.204  8888   US  United States    anonymous     no   yes          10 mins ago
2     68.65.184.223  8888   US  United States    anonymous    yes   yes  3 hours 11 mins ago
3       3.82.203.47  3128   US  United States    anonymous     no   yes  4 hours 38 mins ago
4     20.84.106.205  8214   US  United States  elite proxy    yes   yes  5 hours 40 mins ago
5   150.136.139.194  3128   US  United States  elite proxy    yes   yes  6 hours 30 mins ago
6     172.104.24.22  3128   US  United States    anonymous     no   yes  7 hours 40 mins ago
7     159.65.69.186  9300   US  United States    anonymous     no   yes  7 hours 41 mins ago
8       47.252.4.64  8888   US  United States    anonymous     no   yes  9 hours 34 mins ago
9    12.144.254.185  9080   US  United States    anonymous     no   yes  9 hours 34 mins ago
10    66.94.116.111  3128   US  United States    anonymous     no   yes  9 hours 34 mins ago
11     35.170.197.3  8888   US  United States    anonymous     no   yes  9 hours 34 mins ago
```

Comment: I want to save IP and port in separate lists, e.g :                 ' IP[168.8.172.2, 20.47.108.204, .........]                       PORT[80, 8888, ......] '  How I can achieve this ?

Comment: Just access parts of the `data` array, for example `ip = [row[0] for row in data]`. Adjust the index `0` to get the column you need.